# Faces appearing behind In 'Edit Mode'

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

[image: Images showing the problem]

I'm Using Blender 3.6

In edit mode. When looking at certain angles, or getting closer. Faces (in white) and edges appear through the front faces semi transparently. I can click on them sometimes and its really making working in blender messy and harder. It happens exclusively in 'Edit Mode' What is doing this and how can I disable it?

Image shows in 1. What it looks like 2. What it looks like when I move slightly closer.

In 'Viewport Overlays' settings I can hide the (white) faces at least by unticking 'Faces' under 'Mesh Edit Mode' but that doesn't hide the edges and also makes seeing which faces I have selected harder.

The semi transparent faces fade in as I get closer.

I've tried backface culling options but those do nothing for this problem.

It happens in all shading modes.

X-ray is turned off.

I imagine it's some sort of 'only show front faces' type setting but I can't find anything.

I'm newer to blender so sorry if I'm just being really dumb. It's a tricky problem to describe for me too.

Comment: Hello maybe check the Clip Start and End in the N panel?

Comment: No, unfortunately the clip settings in the N panel clip everything, it does clip the 'behind faces' I'm seeing but along with everything else at the same time, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a complete fresh reinstall. This has fixed the problem. I went from 3.6.0 to version 3.6.2 so perhaps this was a bug fixed in an update. I cannot say myself.

I did ensure to delete any Blender files from my `\AppData\Roaming` folder too.